# Phonegap screen size off by height of status bar?

Tags: android, cordova

One of the pages in my phonegap app is bigger than the screen by exactly the height of the status bar at the top of the screen (this is on Android, on a Google Nexus)... I can disable scrolling (with the touchmove event), but it still hangs off the bottom of the screen... I could fix that by using a fixed height, but then I would need to know the height of the screen and status bar...

I'm OK with making my app fullscreen, but when I tried setting that in my manifest the status bar didn't actually go away (though, phonegap's browser did actually shift up... it no longer hung off the bottom, but was then obscured on the top!)...

Comment: Are you using viewport based CSS, like height: 100vh? I've noticed that with the status bar visible on iOS, 100vh can get thrown off by what appears to be the status bar height.

Answer (score 3):

Remove from your html meta data this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height"/>
```

That made your app full-screen, instead of fullscreen minus statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your OnCreate method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Status bar is still visible, but now my app starts UNDER it (same behavior as my earlier update to the manifest, to make the app fullscreen).